# What is the difference between these different object constructions?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class A
{
public:
    int get(void){return stuff;}
    void set(int s){stuff = s;}

private:
    int stuff;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    A b();
    A* ap = new A;
    A* bp = new A();
}
```

I don't know what the difference is between the four lines in main() exactly and which situations I might use one versus the other (other than being on the stack or heap). I noticed that the fourth line actually initializes "stuff" to 0, whereas the other lines do not. The second line doesn't seem to be anything at all, which seems odd.

Question: What is each line's tradeoffs/meanings (in main())? Whether to use parens or not is confusing to me.

Comment: Don't use `new`. `b` is not an object. By elimination, the only remaining option is `a`.

Comment: For starters, `A b();` doesn't construct an object. Its a [function declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Partly relevant http://stackoverflow.com/q/620137/1171191

Comment: `a` is a local variable and it will be "freed" when it goes out of scope (at the end of the code block), `bp` object will still exist when its pointer goes out of scope unless you explicitly delete it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
A a;
```

That's *default-initialisation*. Since there's no default constructor, each data member is default-initialised; so `a.stuff` is left with an indeterminate value.

```
A b();
```

That declares a function. It doesn't create an object.

```
A* ap = new A;
```

That dynamically allocates an object, and default-initialises it as described above. Since you never delete it, the memory is leaked. You shouldn't use `new` unless you really need a dynamic lifetime; and when you do, you should usually use smart pointers to delete it at the right time, avoiding leaks.

```
A* bp = new A();
```

That dynamically allocates an object and *value-initialises* it. Since there's no default constructor, it value-initialises each data member; so `bp->stuff` is initialised to zero. Again, the memory is leaked.

If the class had a default constructor, then default- and value-initialisation would be identical; both would call the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a; // creates a local automatic variable of type A
    A b(); // See Most Vexing Parse
    A* ap = new A; // creates a new object of type A on the heap using the default constructor (which the compiler implements for you since you didn't declare one)
    A* bp = new A(); // creates a new object of type A on the heap using value initialization (effectively the same as above).
}
```

[Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

In general, you will use `A a;` the vast majority of the time.  `A b();` does not declare an instance of an object.  The dynamic memory versions (which would also require corresponding `delete`s), should only be used if rare cases, and should be wrapped in smart pointer templates (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`) or as part of std containers (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::list`).  It is very rare that you will have to create something on the heap and manage it yourself.